# Cannot give responsive layout to controls

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to get a responsive layout to the window layout, essentially I've three columns and three rows, this is the organization:

**1rst column**

there are all the information of team A, that's the shield and the latest matches under "Performance"

**2rst column**

there are all the latest matches disputed between team A and B

**3rst column**

the same of 1rst column but about on team B

Now for make this predisposition I wrote this code:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!-- Scudetto shield home -->
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
        <Image />
    </Grid>

    <!-- Performance -->
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
        <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <TextBlock Text="Performance" />
        </Viewbox>
        <!--<Label HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">Performance</Label>-->
    </Grid>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="3">
        <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center">Latest matches</Label>
        <TextBox />
        <TextBox Margin="0,5,0,0" />
        <TextBox Margin="0,5,0,0" />
        <TextBox Margin="0,5,0,0" />
        <TextBox Margin="0,5,0,0" />
    </StackPanel>

    <!--shield away -->
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2">
        <Image />
    </Grid>

    <!-- Performance -->
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2">
        <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">Performance</Label>
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

the problems are these:

1. I want to enlarge the font of performance label when the user resize the window, actually I've inserted two situation, one that working bad with viewbox (if you try I've the text too large when the window is to minimum res), and the second situation with a simple label for team B that essentially not working
2. The latest matches of the second column it's not responsive, I need to fit the textbox to height and width, actually working only the width. For the height I mean the space between each textbox that for now is setted as margin.
3. The third column is the same as the first

What I can do for fix this?

Comment: What is the problem with the viewbox? I don't understand what you mean by "if you try I've the text too large when the window is to minimum res"

Comment: @s_mg_ the textblock in viewbox is too large when the windows is on minimum resolution, I need to enlarge it only when the user enlarge the window, but actually when I start the app I get the textblock already too big removing space to other controls